# MySQL Recursive CTE table does not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm learning about recursive functions, Since I need to extract a row for each day in a range of days. This is my current data

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |    from    |     to     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 09-20-2019 | 09-25-2019 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

The goal is to receive my data as follows

```
+----+------------+
| id |    date    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 09-20-2019 |
|  1 | 09-21-2019 |
|  1 | 09-22-2019 |
|  1 | 09-23-2019 |
|  1 | 09-24-2019 |
|  1 | 09-25-2019 |
+----+------------+
```

I'm following an example seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538866/1731057
But for some reason my recursive function is looking for the 'cte' table.

> Query 1 ERROR: Table 'project.cte' doesn't exist

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date_from
    FROM event_dates
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(event_dates.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATE_ADD(event_dates.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= event_dates.date_until
)
select * FROM cte;
```

Comment: Before learniing about recursive functions, learn about data types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Strawberry, is of great help.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of your recursive CTE is off, and the upper half of the union should be a seed base case.  Then, the recursive part should add one day to the previous incoming value:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n, dt) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2019-09-20'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, n, '2019-09-20') FROM cte WHERE n <= 5
)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

[image]

### Demo

Of note, we use `TIMESTAMPADD()` here to get around the problem of the `INTERVAL` expression, which can't really take a variable.

If you want to use this approach to generate a series of dates which matches the from and to values in your table, then you can try a join:

```
SELECT
    t1.dt
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.dt BETWEEN t2.from_date AND t2.to_date;
```

When used this way, the recursive CTE is acting as a *calendar* table.

Comment: Thanks for your time, when I replace your hardcoded '2019-09-20' with 'event_dates.date_from' I get "Unknown table 'event_dates' in field list". Any idea how I can make this variable?

Comment: You can't really do exactly what you have in mind.  The above recursive CTE is intended to be used with a constant date starting point (and an ending point in mind).  _But_, we could generate a calendar table using my answer, and then left join to your table.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the addition, this still leaves 2 dates hardcoded in the cte() function?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The idea here is that you generate a date range with the CTE which is large enough to cover your entire table.

Comment: So with this approach I would have to change the hardcoded dates every few years, too bad mysql doesn't have a more elegant solution for this, thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

**with recursive cte as

```
(select id,`from` as date from date_range
union all
select id+1,date_add(date,interval 1 day)
from cte
where date<(select `to` from date_range)
)
SELECT id, date_format(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date;
```

**